# Replace '&' with '&#038;' in PHP string

Tags: php, xml, rss

I need to convert the `&` in a string to `&#038;` in php.  I have a function to pull in some custom data in to an RSS feed.  In this case it is a url which could look something like `http://google.com?something=here&somethingelse=here&somethingelse=there`

The problem is the amperstand shows in the feed and is not converted to `&#038;` so when I try using simplepie to fetch the feed it throws an error `This XML document is invalid, likely due to invalid characters. XML error: not well-formed (invalid token)`

This is the function I have to add the custom data to the feed:

```
/** Add ACF fields to RSS **/
add_action('rss2_item', 'cupusa_rss2_item');
function cupusa_rss2_item() {
    global $post;

    $memberEvent_link = get_field('member_event_link', $post->ID);

    $output = '';
    if( $post->post_type == 'jobs' ) {
        $job_link_url = get_field('job_link', $post->ID);

            $output .= "<job_link>{$job_link_url}</job_link>";

    }

    if($memberEvent_link){
        $output .= "<member_event_link>{$memberEvent_link}</member_event_link>";
    }

    echo $output;
}
```

When using simplepie it is pulling this `http://google.com?something=here&somethingelse=here&somethingelse=there`  when it should be proper xml like this `http://google.com?something=here&#038;somethingelse=here&#038;somethingelse=there`

**So my question is how do I modify my function above to convert the `&` to `&#038;` for the `$job_link_url` variable?  Sometimes the link may have the & and sometimes it may not.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The `htmlspecialchars` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) will convert all characters which have special meaning in XML.

```
$job_link_url = get_field('job_link', $post->ID);
$xml_safe_job_link_url = htmlspecialchars($job_link_url, ENT_XML1 | ENT_QUOTES);
```

Comment: In addition, if you want to use `&` in an URL, PHP offers you [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).